# I want to host a MySQL server and a Spring Boot Application on the same machine. Should I install Ubuntu server or Ubuntu desktop?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, ubuntu

I have a Dell inspiron 15 3000 laptop. Which one should I replace Windows with?

Answer (score 1):

you  can install ubuntu desktop to host MYSQL server and a Spring Boot application.